# Legend dynamically populated

Tags: r, legend

I have plotted a histogram in R and marked quantiles using `abline()` in vertical intervals. However, I want to plot a legend that shows the corresponding values to the quantiles together with the quantile interval itself.

The current legend is almost there as you can see if you run the example code below. But I can't seem to succeed at aligning the legend interval with its corresponding value and colored line symbol. I tried to use a `data.frame()` to achieve this but it didn't work out.

Any tips or suggestions will be very much appreciated.

```
x<-1:100
quantiles_x<-quantile(x)
hist(x)
abline(v=quantiles_x, col=c("blue", "green","red","yellow","black"))
legend('topright', legend=c(names(quantiles_x), levels(factor(quantiles_x))), lwd=1, col=c("blue","green","red","yellow","black"))
```

Comment: Try it  here http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mihai, this question is in the correct place, delete your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this??

[image]

```
x<-1:100
quantiles_x<-quantile(x)
hist(x)
abline(v=quantiles_x, col=c("blue", "green","red","yellow","black"))
labels <- paste(names(quantiles_x), "[",quantiles_x,"]")
legend('topright', legend=labels, lwd=1, 
        col=c("blue","green","red","yellow","black"))
```